# Powershell Rename Long and Complex Video filenames

Tags: powershell, file-rename, batch-rename, powershell-5.0, windows-11

I just got recent released series called "THE FALL OF THE HOUSE OF USHER". I want to rename it's episode-video files to much easily readable all capitals and dots in filename replaced to spaces(1 dot-1 space, but keeping extension and it's dot intact ofcourse).

So in a nutshell what I wanna do is capture everything before and including "1080p"(and remove the rest of the junk) in all these filenames and rename them by capitalizing all and putting spaces instead of dots and keeping the same extension if it's .mkv or .mp4.

```
The.Fall.of.the.House.of.Usher.S01E08.The.Raven.1080p.x264.Hindi.English.Msubs.MoviesMod.org
The.Fall.of.the.House.of.Usher.S01E07.The.Pit.and.the.Pendulum.1080p.x264.Hindi.English.Msubs.MoviesMod.org
....
....
```

How do I do that ? I do have this code but it has been designed for different specific kinda filename of different movie, how do I change it and make a copy of code compatible with episode-video filename format like aforementioned ??

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mkv | where-object {$_.length -gt 524288000} | Where {$_.BaseName -CNotMatch "^[A-z\s\d]+$"} | Foreach {$FileName = [Regex]::Match($_, "^(.*?)202[2|3]").Value; $FileName = $FileName -replace '\.', ' '; $FileName = $FileName.ToUpper() + ' 1080p.mkv'; rename-item -Path $_.fullname -NewName $FileName}
```

If we can keep "1080p" intact too, it will be cherry on the top, thanks!!

Comment: _I wanna do is capture everything before and including "1080p"_... so its safe to assume all files __will have__ `1080p` in their name?

Comment: Mostly they have 1080p, but some do have 720p too, depending on resolution of video, if can accomodate both with pipe then good or just 1080p also would be fine.

Comment: something like this? `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(('The.Fall.of.the.House.of.Usher.S01E08.The.Raven.1080p.x264.Hindi.English.Msubs.MoviesMod.org' -replace '(?<=1080p|720p).+' -replace '\.', ' '))`

Comment: `ToTitleCase` is not very smart tho. you also need to handle concatenating the extension after

Comment: Yeah mostly good, will this be able to rename all episode files, I have like 7-8 of them each with different episode name, if all caps is not feasible then title case would work, but let's see if it's feasible somehow

Comment: oh wait, you were looking to have all capitalized, my bad. then its as simple as `.ToUpper()` it instead of `ToTitleCase()` it. If that regex works I can post an answer

Comment: Yes this seems great, let's see the final Regex and Code for bulk-renaming (rename all episodes in one pass/go of command run), I am ready for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick, the first `-replace '(?<=1080p|720p).+'` would be creating a new string removing everything after `1080p` or `720p` then the following `-replace '\.', ' '` will replace every `.` for a   and lastly `ToUpper()` will capitalize the string. The rest is concatenating that string with the extension.

```bash
$validExtensions = '.mkv', '.mp4'
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Where-Object Extension -In $validExtensions |
    Where-Object Length -GT 500mb |
    Rename-Item -NewName {
        ($_.BaseName -replace '(?<=1080p|720p).+' -replace '\.', ' ').ToUpper() + $_.Extension
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for great answer, upvoted and will accept it in shortwhile. Thanks again!